# MIPS asm to C: How to set .section directives

Tags: c, assembly, mips, nios

So I'm trying to make an exception handler for the NIOS II Audio Core in C.

I'm wondering how do I convert...

> .section .exceptions, "ax"

... from MIPS asm to C?

I know this...

> **attribute** ((section(".exceptions)))

is equivalent to...

> .section .exceptions

but how do I include the .section directives?

I've tried this...

> **attribute** ((section(".exceptions, \"ax\"")))

but the compiler doesn't like anything after the s in exceptions.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can cheat and emit appropriate target assembler directive directly with __asm__(). As far as I can tell there's no standard way to control section attributes from C. Even __attribute__((section...)) is not available on all platforms, so you will have to do something that is target-specific anyways.